# MDI child Not moving to the front

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, mdichild

Hope your well.

I was wondering if some-one can help me. I am creating a new point of sales project and I have just created a MDI welcome main screen that appears after my login page. I have added buttons, background and a logo to the main welcome MDI patent screen. I have also created a form for each button and made them into a mdi child, however they keep ending up behind the buttons and logo and was wondering if any-one knows how to bring them to the front over the buttons and logo, the form does however come in front of the background. I have tried the .BringToFront but that doesn't work and I have also tried sending the main welcome screen to the back but when I do that it disappears as if it minimises itself.

Example of the code I'm using

```
private void btnQuickSales_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   QuickSale sale = new QuickSale();
   sale.MdiParent = this;
   sale.Show();
   sale.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: I can see the issue you mean ...  I have a questions -  Are you looking only for a modal dialog box behavior? Or was there a specific reason to make the parent form an MDI container ?

Comment: Usually you create a docked panel in the MDI parent that is used to host the parent's controls.  Since it's docked the MDI children won't stray into that space.

Comment: Thanks Kapoor and Same For the reply.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to programming and I'm creating a simple program that incorporates everything I've learnt so far, I created a MDI to host all the different forms like the quick sale form, account sales form and adding new employees. The reason I've done an MDI was to showcase some buttons with images and the look and feel of of the program to spice things up a bit. I thought about a Docked panel but can't seem to make it look as cool as if I add the buttons and images.

Comment: Hey!  did you already find a solution ? Or shall I make a suggestion as I do in my applications ?

Comment: Hi Kapoor thanks for the reply, I was told to try childform.focus and it does work to some extent but not the way I was hoping, A suggestion would be great. Thanks